# How to align these two rows using Bootstrap 2.3.1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue in styling the form controls I have using Bootstrap 2.3.2

I have two rows inside a panel. Each row is divided into two spans. Each span has a form. 
Apparently, the rows are semi-similar to each other, but they are not aligned. **Is there any way to align them with overriding the whole style of the bootstrap?**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Summary Report
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <label>Weekly Total</label>
                     <input type="text" value="22MM" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <label>Days' Total</label>
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                     <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid top-buffer">
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <label>Monthly Per Total</label>
                     <input type="text" value="33MM" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="form-inline text-center">
                    <label>Monthly Total</label>
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                    <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a snapshot of the what I've gotten so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just space the labels and inputs with the spanX class and align the labels as I need them (text-left , text-right etc), so to apply that to your original code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Summary Report
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label class="span4 text-right">Weekly Total</label>
                <input class="span8" type="text" value="22MM" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label class="span4 text-right">Days' Total</label>
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid top-buffer">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label  class="span4 text-right">Monthly Per Total</label>
                <input  class="span8" type="text" value="33MM" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="form-inline ">
                <label class="span4 text-right">Monthly Total</label>
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
                <input type="text" value="111" class="input-mini span1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```